# How can I override the __str__ method of sympy.core.numbers.Float?

Tags: python, sympy

I am trying to overcome the flaws of sub-classing Python's float by using a different class hierarchy of numbers. However the following code:

```
from sympy import *
import sympy.core.numbers

f = 1.123456789
n = N(f, 8)

print n
print type(n)

sympy.core.numbers.Float.__str__ = lambda f: "{:.8f}".format(f)

print n
```

yields the error:

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'numbers'

How can I overcome this?

Comment: I have never used sympy module -- but I think you'd want `N.__str__`, don't you?

Comment: `from sympy.core.numbers import Float; Float.__str__ = lambda f: "{:.8f}".format(f)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does what you need:

**Code:**

```
from sympy.core.numbers import Float
Float.__str__ = lambda f: "{:.8f}".format(float(f))
```

**Test Code:**

```
from sympy import N
from sympy.core.numbers import Float

f = 1.123456789
n = N(f, 8)

Float.__str__ = lambda f: "{:.8f}".format(float(f))

print n
```

**Results:**

```
1.12345679
```

Answer (score 1):

Monkeypatching `__str__` is bad practice in this situation, as SymPy already has a built in way to modify how SymPy objects are printed, by subclassing the printers. Here I've taken and modified the original [`sympy.printing.str.StrPrinter._print_Float`](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/b50ac8be346940a0537beb6b446dcf733a6bf2ee/sympy/printing/str.py#L561).

```
from sympy.printing.str import StrPrinter

class MyStrPrinter(StrPrinter)
    def _print_Float(self, expr):
        return '{:.8f}'.format(expr)
```

Then use `MyStrPrinter().doprint` instead of `str`. You can also make `str` itself use this by using

```
from sympy import init_printing

init_printing(pretty_print=False, str_printer=MyStrPrinter().doprint)
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to some bad name choices, the `sympy.core.core` submodule gets imported over the "real" `sympy.core` subpackage, so attempting to access `sympy.core` gets you `sympy.core.core`, and attempting to access `sympy.core.numbers` gets you an `AttributeError`.

There are a number of ways you can work around this. SymPy provides access to the class you want as `sympy.Float`, for example:

```
import sympy
do_whatever_with(sympy.Float)
```